# Multiple dependent Projects in TFService

Tags: .net, tfs, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I am using the Team Foundation Service as my source control and to build CI. Now I have dependent Projects. How can I use the output from one as a reference for the other project? Basicly Project B needs Project A.

I can just copy the Project A compiled DLL to Project B and it will somehow work. But that is not a real solution. For the CI works smooth it should always use the current Project A DLL out of the build system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you dont check in any dll's which generates during the build. Only 3rd party dlls you have to check in.

In your case now, you can reference your ProjectA to your PrjectB. To do this you need to open up you Visual Studio, Solution Explorer.

1. Right Click on Project B, add reference.
2. Click on  Solution->Projects
3. Then Click on the project you want to reference.

Once you aaded this new reference, rebuild the solution and Check in again. Now you will get the TFService Build without customizing your build template.

Good Luck.

Comment: Yes, this works fine, IF the projects are in the same Solution. 
Project A is also needed for Project D and E. (D and E depends on A)
In the Solution of A are already three Projects. The main DLL Project, an UnitTest Project and a Demo Project. Do u suggest, that i add all these Projects to every Solutions?

Comment: Yes, you can create one solution with as many as project you want. Say for example: MySolution (solution name) and you can have different project like ProjectA, ProjectB, ProjectC, ProjectD etc. By doing this you can add ProjectA as reference to B,C and D so on.

Comment: Ok, i will mark this as anwser. Maybe i will ask another question to this topic next week regarding the build process - or maybe some features will be added to TFService.

Comment: Not a problem, we are here to help if we can! Good Luck with your build process :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom build which builds nuget packages from project A and then store them on a shared folder and reference these packages in project B. Clean and easy!

In case you don't want to create the build task on your own: [Nugetter](http://nugetter.codeplex.com/) should be able to help you build and deploy the packages on the TFS.

See offical NuGet documentation:

[Creating and Publishing a Package](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package)

[Hosting Your Own NuGet Feeds](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds)

Comment: As far as i know, you cannot use custom builds with Team Foundation SERVICE. (On TFServer this would be a nice solution.)

Comment: I don't have access at the moment to a TFService. But according to this description (http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/build/setup-ci-build-in-vs) it should be possible to select a Build Template and you should be able to check in a custom BuildTemplate and then use this instead of the default one. Nugetter should provide you with a Template if you want to test it out without coding one on your own.

Comment: Thx, i found out, that you can create a custom BuildTemplate only as an on-premisis build template. But why would i want to use Team Foundation Service, when i have to build the stuff on my machines? I am searching for a online-only version.